# Как организовать подгрузку элементов?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-asynctask

Есть лента которая реализована при помощи `RecyclerView`, заполняю её при помощи `AsyncTask`.

Сейчас у меня идет постоянная загрузка постов с сервера и динамическое заполнение ленты.

Вопрос, как мне отследить что пользователь пролистал ленту к примеру до 50-го элемента после чего выполнить подгрузку новых постов

Comment: для асинхронной работы с списками есть специальный класс `AsyncTaskLoader`, рекомендуется использовать его, так как помимо асинхронной работы он контролирует изменение состояния, например, при повороте устройства и некоторые другие функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить к `RecyclerView` `ScrollListener`:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0) {
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }
    }
});
```

При скролле списка вызывается метод `onScrolled(...)` в котором проверяется условие `dy > 0`, которое означает, что список был проскроллен вниз.

Далее происходит получение номера последнего видимого элемента (на текущий момент), в зависимости от этого номера можете начинать загрузку следующих элементов.

Далее нужно проверить: если в данный момент идет загрузка, то делать ничего не нужно, если же элементы еще не загружаются, то нужно стартовать загрузку.

Тут еще есть несколько подводных камней, но общая идея такова.

И еще: с `AsyncTask` следует работать очень аккуратно: если `AsyncTask` – поле класса активити, то при изменении конфигурации устройства загруженные данные Вы уже не получите.

Можно, например, использовать `AsyncTaskLoader`, либо `AsyncTask` в retain-фрагменте (если Вы их используете), либо воспользоваться другими способами загрузки данных с сети, например, RoboSpice, либо какими-то другими.